# Having problems uploading files to a web service (Web Forms)

Tags: c#, webforms

I am working with Asp.net 2.0 Web Forms and I would like to upload a file to a web service.  I have tried using jQuery.Upload library to no avail.  Someone mentioned to me about using the jquery.form plugin and posting an action on a Form to post to the web service.

Can someone recommend to me a good approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On your FORM tag, set the "action" attribute as the URL of the web service.
2. Inside your FORM tag, add the FileUpload web control (`<asp:FileUpload runat="server" />`).